# change img source based on time of day using date("h:i:sa")

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good afternoon.

I want to change the background color and two images based on the time of day, specifically sunrise and sunset.

I wrote this code, thinking that getting the comparison for sunrise/sunset would be easy, but I've hit a snag in how to best check for the correct time range in my `if - else` statement. Essentially I cannot seem to find anything to show how to represent those time ranges. I have the

I think also that the else is redundant because the default will be the first variable anyway.

My code:

```
<?php

    $pic1 = "images/full_top_bg_01.png";
    $pic2 = "images/full_top_bg_02.png";
    $bgcolor = "#3E7B98";


    $hour = date('G');

    if( $hour < 13 ){

    $pic1 = "images/full_top_bg_01.png";
    $pic2 = "images/full_top_bg_02.png";
    $bgcolor = "#3e7b98";


  } else if( $hour < 15 ){

    $pic1 = "images/full_top_bg_01-night.png";
    $pic2 = "images/full_top_bg_02_night.png";
    $bgcolor = "#333333";

  }
  else {
    $pic1 = "images/full_top_bg_01.png";
    $pic2 = "images/full_top_bg_02.png";
    $bgcolor = "#333333";
  }
?>
```

Then the variables are set in the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid top_container" style="background-color:<?php echo $bgcolor;?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $pic1;?>" class="img-responsive" alt="clouds1">
    <img src="<?php echo $pic2;?>" class="img-responsive" alt="clouds2">
</div>
```

So my question here is essentially: a) do I need an array to represent the time range and b) is my `else if` statement even necessary?

Comment: Correction: Use `==` as opposed to `=` in your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is check the hour of the day.

```
<?php

// Using "G" in the date to get the 24-hour hour of the day
// instead of the 12-hour (am/pm) hour.
$hour = date('G');

if ( $hour < 12 ) {
  // Morning picture
}
else if ( $hour < 18 ) {
  // Afternoon
}
else {
 // Evening
}

?>
```

You can add as many conditions as you would like to pinpoint many more hours of the day.

Comment: Oddly this doesn't seem to be working. Syntax-wise it makes perfect sense.  I changed the `$hour` parameters to lower numbers to see if it works and I do not see a change. Am I missing something?

Comment: I changed my code to reflect what you had suggested.

Comment: Add a final `else` condition. The `$hour` may be outside of the params of the other two `if` conditions.

Comment: The last `else` statement seems to disregard any time and that is what is displayed.

Comment: What does `echo $hour` produce? It may not be what you think it is

Comment: it is returning 0. Hence why it is not working, probably.

Comment: Learning how to debug is very important. Set your timezone and try again.

Comment: if I change the greater than to a less than on the `else if` it works, but logically that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You're just setting this based on the time of day of the server, not the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is reading this - here is a solution for a time range that worked:

```
$hour = date('G');

if( $hour < 6 && $hour > 18 ){

$pic1 = "images/full_top_bg_01.png";
$pic2 = "images/full_top_bg_02.png";
$bgcolor = "#3E7B98";

} else if( $hour > 18 && $hour < 6 ){

$pic1 = "images/full_top_bg_01-night.png";
$pic2 = "images/full_top_bg_02_night.png";
$bgcolor = "#333333";

}
```

using the range `$hour < 6 && $hour > 18` combined with the other range, I was able to create a time range.